# How to simulate paste(CTRL + V) using AUTO IT in Word Document

Tags: autoit

**Objectives -**

1. Open the target app using AutoIy
2. Take a printscreen (ALT + PRTSCREEN) of the opened app(step 1)
3. Open a new word document
4. Paste the screenshot on word document

**Issue:**
I am able to complete the first two step, however I am not able to paste the screenshot in Word document.

**Root Cause**

I am able to take the print screen using SEND ("!{PRINTSCREEN}") and open word document using UDF _WORD_DOCADD, but I am not able to paste from clipboard. The issue is, when I am using WinWaitActive to activate the document, the document is still not active and hence SEND ("^V") is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to solve my problem. Steps followed are -

1. Simulate ALT + PRNTSCRN
2. Open Clipboard
3. GetData from Clipboard as BITMAP
4. Save the data as JPG using GDIPLUS_IMAGE_SAVETOFILE
5. Use DOCADD to open new document and _Word_DocPictureAdd to save the image to word document.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Send incorrectly to send the Ctrl+V. With a capitol V, it will be interpreted by AutoIt as Ctrl+Shift+V (see helpfile for details). Instead what you want to use is `Send("^v")`.

WinWaitActive does not activate the document, it simply waits for it to become active, use WinActivate to activate word.

The correct way to paste though is to use the word com object, something like: `$oWord.Activedocument.Range.paste`. That will work without word being active or visible.

Also, there are better ways to screenshot than sending Alt+Printscreen.

All these steps are very well documented, and have been done many times before.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I used _ScreenCapture_CaptureWnd to take a screenshot. First time, the image saved was clean and without any overlap, but when I executed the program again, the screenshot was not clean. This time again the screenshot has text from another screen. What is going wrong. I dont see any thing mentioned about screen capture in the manual.